# How to safely dismiss the apple pay screen

Tags: iphone, apple-pay

I like the apple pay feature. however there are times when the apple pay pops up even though I am not buying anything or even close to a shop.

The problem is that when the apple pay screen pops up, if I touch the touch id then it will end up making a payment.

I want a sure shot way of safely dismissing the apple pay screen when it pops up without a reason.

I am using iphone 8 plus with latest ios 11.

Answer (score 2):

Press the home button with a finger not registered with TouchID or press the On/Off button on the right side of the phone. Either will dismiss the Apple Pay window.

Comment: I use a fingernail rather than unregistered finger - that way you don't get the 'wrong finger' error.